# Newbie to Java, wondering about if statements and strings that are read by Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, conditional-statements, string-comparison

So, just started with `Java` today and I was playing around with the `Scanner` object after having watched a tutorial on how the guy used it to find the area of a triangle. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but, I decided to mess about and see if I could incorporate an "if" statement into it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    /*
     * in = input from a keyboard or other device.
     * System is a class.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        {
            String password;
            //this is our variable - password

            System.out.print("Enter your password:");
            password = sc.next();
            //we have gotten the user to input the words, now to work on displaying a final message
            //using if

            if (password.equals(one))
                System.out.println("You have logged in successfully");
        }

    }

}
```

That's my code and I apologize if it looks shoddy - still trying to learn.

My issue is, I want my if statement to only go through if they input a specific password ("one"). However, I get an error with this because it says the value 'one' cannot be resolved to a variable. When I input numbers, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Using an IDE with syntax correction is a great way to learn a new programming language, often they tell you quickly about newbie mistakes with a reason. Netbeans and Eclipse are the leading favorites, check them out one day.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, and, that's how I even knew where to find the error! Though, are there any other settings to turn on for Eclipse that'll help even more?

Comment: Eclipse does lots of cool guy things, most of which you wont notice or ever use. I'm still learning it myself. Short of just reading the documentation i'm not sure how easy it is to "learn" Eclipse.

Comment: I have updated my answer and hope it will give you some idea of why the code you've posted does not work the way you expect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, a class is always capitalized so `public class test` should be `public class Test`.

You need to compare explicitely with a String. As `one` is defined nowhere, your code will not work.

replace:

```
if (password.equals(one))
```

with

```
if (password.equals("one"))
```

and you are good to go.

Instead, you could also declare the password in the header of your Class :

```
String pw = "one";
```

and then check

```
if (password.equals(pw))
```

But remember that it is *never* safe to treat passwords this way, in *any* programming language. The password should be hashed and stored in a database. However as you are still learning, I would probably consider the second method (declaring the string you want to compare to) as the 'cleaner' way to go.

**Edit** - How your code would work with simple variable declaration

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {

    String pw = "one";
    String pw2;

    /* this is the constructor for your class 
    you can override existing variables or 
    set a variable that is declared in the header of your class
    inside the constructor of your class. It will run whenever you
    create a new object for that class */

    public Test(String pw2Param) {
         this.pw2 = pw2Param;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        {    
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            // instantiate an object that will hold the information you need 
            Test obj = new Test("two");
            System.out.println(obj.pw);
            // "one"
            System.out.println(obj.pw2);
            // "two"

            System.out.println("Enter your password:");
            String password = sc.next();

            if (password.equals(obj.pw)) {
                System.out.println("You have typed 'one' and logged in successfully");
            } else if(password.equals(obj.pw2)) {
                System.out.println("You have typed 'two' and logged in successfully");
            } else {
                System.out.println("I didn't get that");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this makes some sense :)

I am also a beginner, but i found it to be good habit to compile my java code using `javac` in my console. It is ruthless in comparison to any ide that I've used and will point you at some general errors which an ide might forgive/correct for you.

Comment: Yeah! I was just playing around, haha. Wouldn't ever treat passwords this way - ever. Just something to play around with and thank you so long much for your help! Also, for your second option with the whole declaring what the String is in my header, do I have to add static to it or no? Cause, I tried that with just your code and it didn't work but adding static to it worked, so, I was just wondering.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt check if you were instantiating an object of your class. As you arent the pw variable will not instantiate if it's not set static, so you're right.

Comment: I can kinda understand where your code is going to - but, alas, my lack of knowledge on constructors and instantiates loses me. But, I'll save this code and come back to it when I've gotten further with Java! Thanks again, for your extra help in showing me what it could become.

Comment: Do not fear, Java is great for understanding the concepts of object oriented programming. You will have a steep learning curve if you check some of the many tutorials on the net

Answer (score 2):

instead

```
if (password.equals(one))//here one is treated as variable and you are not declared at all in your class.
```

use

```
if (password.equals("one"))//as string, the value should in double qoutes
```

If you write like

```
   String one="one";
```

in your program before the `if` statement then

```
  if (password.equals(one))//correct
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String one = "one";
if (password.equals(one))
    ......
```

this will solve your problem, as you are declaring one, now, sothat it will be resolved.

these are very small issues in coding , as the comments above suggests, using an IDE can fix these kind of coding errors,while writing the code itself.